# Convert a string (containing characters and float) to double in c++

Tags: c++, string, math

I had an assignment of fractions in which the user sends input as a/b, *but the a and b were simple integers and not negative or floats and extracting them was easy **using if else statements***

But right now I'm making a complex number (calculator type) program. And I'm actually taking a string in form of a + bi (where a and b can integer or float or both).
I'm having difficulty how to go about without using a lot of extra lines.

---

*Edited:* My question was actually how to extract  'Real & Imaginary Part' from a + bi.

**e.g. *Input:* 3.45 - 9.87 i** and get `float Real` = 3.45 and `float Imaginary` = 9.87 out

I'm working in c++ and using visual studio

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: What is your question ? Can you be more clear?

Comment: I would suggest using [boost.spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) but that seems quite overkill :)

Comment: I'm new to c++ and didn't know about stringstream s, etc. I was bored and decided to make a program on the weekend but I didn't expect I would be so far behind, so thanks for the answers @pentadecagon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the iostreams library provides nicely overloaded operators, you can read the components of the expression roughly like this:

```
string s = "3.45 - 9.87 i";
istringstream ist( s );
double re, im;
char op, ki;
ist >> re >> op >> im >> ki;
// op == '-'      
// ki == 'i'
complex<double> a( re, op == '-' ? -im : im );
```

From there it should be easy to support more flexible expressions as well.